# Запятая перед "как чего"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "как чего" в следующем предложении?

*Расскажи, как чего.*

Answer (score 1):

***Расскажи, как чего.***

Запятая ставится. Это выражение имеет значение *как и что*.

Пример:

― Да вот, насчет Митьки… Узнать, **как чего**. ― Я бы этого Митьку… знаешь. Близко к деревне бы не пустил. [Василий Белов. Привычное дело (1967)

Comment: Один (первый) пример без сомнения в строку, а другие... К чему они? Это другие типы.